# Is this set dense in $\mathcal{C}^{\infty} (\mathbb{S}^3 , \mathbb{R}^3 ) $?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, differential-topology

Consider $\mathcal{F} = {\{ f:\mathbb{S}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3; f\mbox{ is smooth} \}}$ and the metric $d: \mathcal{F}\times  \mathcal{F} \to \mathbb{R} $
$$d(f,g) = |f-g| = \sup_{p\in \mathbb{S}^3} \|f(p) - g(p)\|, $$
it is easy to see that $(\mathcal{F}, d)$ is a metric space.
Let $T^2 \subset \mathbb{S}^3$ be the set
$$T^2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot \mathbb{T}^2 = \left\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in \mathbb{S}^3 ; \ x_1^2 + x_2^2 = x_3^2 + x_4^2 = \frac{1}{2} \right\}. $$

> **Question:** Is the set $\mathcal{A} = \{f\in \mathcal{F};\ f(p)\neq 0 \ \  \forall\ p\in T^2 \}$ dense in $\mathcal{F}$?

This seems true but I'm a little confused about how I supposed to approach this problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: use transversallity theorem.

Comment: we know that the functions $f: \mathbb{S}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, such that $f(p) =0 $ $\Rightarrow$ $\text{d}f_p T_p\mathbb{S}^3 = \mathbb{R}^3$ are dense, why this imply the result?

Comment: I understood that a function with such property has only finitely many vanishing points. But I don't know how to get rid of these vanishing points, without creating new ones

Comment: intuitively, since there are only finitely many points in the inverse image of $0$ so if one of those pre-images is on $T^2$, then you can perturb the function by a very small amount and push that point away from $T^2$...now try to argue in this line.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use Sard's Theorem and prove that there is some vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^3$ arbitrarily close to zero which is not in $f(T^2)$. Thus, $\tilde f=f-v$ has no zeros in $T^2$ (and can be made arbitrarily close to $f$. Note also that $\mathcal A$ is open. So this proves that the set is open and dense. Anyway, jet transversality is a mind-opening subject and is worth looking at it.